# Average based on certain condition in the numerator

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, correlated-subquery

I have two tables WIP and ROS, both tables have plenty of columns but main columns required are
Branch, Date, LC and, 'DN' and 'JCN' are used to join two tables and the output should be in below format 
Branch, Date,count(* based on condition)/count(*)

As mentioned, both tables have many columns but for my query: WIP contains Branch, Status,Date and DN columns and ROS contains Branch,LC and JCN columns

I have used case case statement like below:

```
select a.Branch,[Billed Date],avg(case when LC in 
('A22D','SB15','SB16','AT01','AT02','AT03') then 1.0 else 0 end)
from WIP a join ROS b on a.DN = b.JCN
where a.[Status] = 'BILLED' and SUBSTRING(a.DN,1,3) = 'XJC'
group by a.Branch,[Billed Date]
order by 1,2
```

I am trying to get results using joins and correlated sub-query without using case statement

I've used below query, but getting incorrect result.

```
 select a.Branch,[Billed Date], 
            1.0*(select count(*) from ROS where LC in ('A22D','SB15','SB16','AT01','AT02','AT03') and c.Branch = 
 a.Branch )/(select count(*) from ROS d where d.Branch = a.Branch)
 from WIP a join ROS b on a.DN = b.JCN
 where a.[Status] = 'BILLED' and SUBSTRING(a.DN,1,3) = 'XJC'
 order by 1,2
```

I am expecting output to be:

```
 Branch     Date      Average_Jobs
   A     2019-06-01       0.11
   B     2019-06-01       0.09
   C     2019-06-01       0.12
   A     2019-06-02       0.12
   B     2019-06-02       0.10
   C     2019-06-02       0.13
```

Where the average column is derived from count of LCs that are A22D,SB15,SB16,AT01,AT02,AT03 etc divided overall LC count, for every Branch and every day.

I am getting below output with correlated subquery, I know the avg numbers are all wrong:

```
Branch  Date        Avg
A   2019-06-01  0.032258065
A   2019-06-02  0.032258065
A   2019-06-03  0.032258065
A   2019-06-04  0.032258065
A   2019-06-05  0.032258065
A   2019-06-06  0.032258065
B   2019-06-01  0.032183908
B   2019-06-02  0.032183908
B   2019-06-03  0.032183908
B   2019-06-04  0.032183908
B   2019-06-05  0.032183908
B   2019-06-06  0.032183908
C   2019-06-01  0.032183908
C   2019-06-02  0.032183908
C   2019-06-03  0.032183908
C   2019-06-04  0.032183908
C   2019-06-05  0.032183908
C   2019-06-06  0.032183908
```

*****EDIT:
I need a modification to the query as it didn't give me correct results upon manual checking. The problem is that DN is primary key and JCN is foreign key, which has many duplicates under LC column for EX:

```
 WIP Table           ROS Table
    DN             JCN        LC
    11A            11A        A21X
    12A            11A        SB15
     .             11A        AT09
     .             11A        A22A 
     .             12A        A22A
     .             12A        AT11  
                   12A        SB01
```

The output of my query gives the average as 14.28% because out of 7 rows, the condition is met with 'SB15' in the second row. Whereas what I need the average to be 50%. That's because there are two entries under DN column: 11A and 12A, and only one of them has a LC that we are interested in i.e. 'SB15'. Therefore the average is 1/2 = .5 of 50%. I know I need to take ratios of DISTINCT values of JCN or DN to get the correct result, I used DISTINCT as below but not getting correct result:

```
 select a.Branch,[Billed Date],avg(case when LC in 
 ('A22D','SB15','SB16','AT01','AT02','AT03') then 1.0 else 0 end)
 from WIP a join (select distinct JCN,LC from ROS) b on a.DN = b.JCN
 where a.[Status] = 'BILLED' and SUBSTRING(a.DN,1,3) = 'XJC'
 group by a.Branch,[Billed Date]
 order by 1,2
```

Could someone please let me know how to get that?

Comment: What is incorrect, exactly? Provide sample data for the  expected result

Comment: table definitions please

Comment: The result you get don't depend on date because you subqueries don't depend on it.  To get  what you wish add `a.[Billed Date]` argument to them. If `ROS` tble has no date column to compare with  `a.[Billed Date]` stick to `CASE` version

Comment: I tried adding one more condition wherein I've joined using DN and JCN as well: 
But now I am getting "Divide by zero error encountered." error, Could you please let me know why do I need to add using 'Date' column, and yes, Date columns is not there in ROS.

Comment: If there is no date column in `ROS`, your  `ROS`-subquery version is not relevant to the problem as you wish to get a date-depending result. What's wrong with the `case` version?

Comment: Just wanted to cross check if the results both way are same, just to make sure I get the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  all_fields.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Branch,
      MAX(Date)
    FROM
       yourtable
    GROUP BY
      Branch
   ) AS max_recs
LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable AS all_fields ON max_recs.id = all_fields.id
```